# Python Modules do not import yet requirement already satisfied

Tags: python, pip

I am importing two python modules on my school computer (I cannot use cmd, I do not have enough experience with powershell), pygame and pyglet. I imported these modules last year and had no problems, this year I have started having problems. I tried reinstalling them.
I have imported them via pip.

```
import pip
pip.main(["install", "--user", "pygame"])
```

and

```
import pip
pip.main(["install", "--user", "pyglet"])
```

It says that this requirement has already been meet.

When I import it into my code it says
[image]

I have tried other methods and they all return the same result.
What can I do?

Comment: If the packages were just installed (and vscode is configured properly), restarting vscode should work.  If not, check whether there's a mismatch between the python version you're running your code with (for example using `python --version` or `py --version`, etc in the vscode terminal) and the interpreter being used/expected by vscode (right side of the status bar at the bottom, to the right of "Python")

Comment: Thanks @jedwards! I restarted vscode and checked my settings and workplace trust was in restricted mode ‍♂️. Fixed it and now it's working fine!

Comment: glad you figured it out, I didn't even think of that "feature" because I disabled it globally immediately :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If restarting vscode doesn't work to cause pylance to find new packages, it sounds like there's a mismatch between the interpreter you're using to run your programs (and where you installed the packages via pip) and the interpreter vscode/pylance is using for language support.

With those restrictions, try this:

First, create a script with

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
print(sys.executable)
```

and run it (however you're running scripts).

You should get output like:

```
3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
C:\Python\Python310\python.exe
```

Then, in the bottom right of vscode there's a statusbar and at the right side you should see something like:
[image: statusbar]

Here it shows that vscode is using the 3.10.2 64-bit version of the interpreter.

If you click the version label (3.10.2 64-bit in my case), you should get a pop-up at the top of your screen, like:

[image]

Make sure you select the interpreter that you're using (as identified by the output of that simple 3-line script -- both the interpreter version and the path).

Answer (score 0):

For me this was a version mismatch: VSCode was using a different interpreter version (3.10) than the packages were installed for (3.9).

You can correct this by clicking the Python version in the status bar (to the right of the word Python). Multiple options should show up, switching to 3.8.9 worked for me.